# Oracle Partition Pruning not working when left outer join is used

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have one table that is list partitioned on a numeric column (row_id),

```
TABLEA (ROW_ID NUMERIC(38), TB_KEY NUMERIC(38), ROW_DATA VARCHAR(20));
```

Partition pruning **works** when i query from table with no joins:

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLEA A
WHERE ROW_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLEB WHERE DT_COL = SYSDATE);
```

Partition Pruning **fails** when I do left outer join to TableB

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLEA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TB_KET = B.TB_KEY
WHERE ROW_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLEB WHERE DT_COL = SYSDATE);
```

Partition Pruning **works** when I change left outer join to inner join

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TB_KET = B.TB_KEY
WHERE ROW_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLEB WHERE DT_COL = SYSDATE);
```

Partition Pruning **works** when I do left outer join to TableB and do not use IN clause

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLEA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TB_KET = B.TB_KEY
WHERE ROW_ID = 123;
```

Partition Pruning **works** when I do left outer join to TableB and use static values for IN clause

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLEA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TB_KET = B.TB_KEY
WHERE ROW_ID IN (123, 345);
```

Can someone explain me why left outer join will cause partition pruning to fail, when i query on column that table is partitioned on using IN clause with result from subquery?

Answer (score 1):

The answer on Oracle 11g is YES, the partition pruning works fine.

There are three main access patterns in your setup, with the `list partitioned` table `TABLEA`, lets go all of them through. Note, that I'm using
simplest possible statements to illustrated the behavior.

**Access with keys in equal predicate or in IN List**

The simplest case is using a literal in an equal predicate on the partition key:

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLEA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TB_KET = B.TB_KEY
WHERE A.ROW_ID = 123;
```

This leads to following execution plan

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |        |     1 |    51 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER       |        |     1 |    51 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   2 |   PARTITION LIST SINGLE|        |     1 |    38 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | TABLEA |     1 |    38 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |
|   4 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | TABLEB |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("A"."TB_KET"="B"."TB_KEY"(+))
   3 - filter("A"."ROW_ID"=123)
```

Only the relevant partition ot TABLEA is accessed (here the partition #2) - see the columns `Pstart` and `Pstop`.

Slightly complicated, but similar, is the case with in `IN LIST`

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLEA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TB_KET = B.TB_KEY
WHERE ROW_ID IN (123, 345);

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |        |     1 |    51 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER       |        |     1 |    51 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   2 |   PARTITION LIST INLIST|        |     1 |    38 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |KEY(I) |KEY(I) |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | TABLEA |     1 |    38 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |KEY(I) |KEY(I) |
|   4 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | TABLEB |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("A"."TB_KET"="B"."TB_KEY"(+))
   3 - filter("A"."ROW_ID"=123 OR "A"."ROW_ID"=345)
```

In this case more partitions can be accessed, but only those partitions, that contains the keys from the `IN LIST` are considered.

Same is valid for access using bind variable.

**Access with keys from a table using NESTED LOOPS**

More complicated is the case where the two tables are joined. While using a **nested loop** join for each key from `TABLEB` the 
`TABLEA` is accessed. This means that for each key only the one partition where the key is located is accessed.

```
SELECT  A.* FROM TABLEA A
WHERE ROW_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLEB WHERE DT_COL = SYSDATE);

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |        |     1 |    60 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS            |        |     1 |    60 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   2 |   SORT UNIQUE            |        |     1 |    22 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | TABLEB |     1 |    22 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |   PARTITION LIST ITERATOR|        |   100K|  3710K|     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | TABLEA |   100K|  3710K|     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Again there is a partition pruning `KEY` - `KEY`, so only partitions with key from `TABLEB` are accessed, but from the nature of nested loops, one partition can be accessed several times (for different keys).

**Access with keys from a table using HASH JOIN**

Using `HASH JOIN` is the most complicated case, where the partition pruning must happen *before* the join started. Here is the [Bloom Filter](https://antognini.ch/papers/BloomFilters20080620.pdf) at work.

How does it work? After scanning the `TABLEB` Oracle knows all relevant keys from it, those keys can be mapped to the relevant partitions and a
the `Bloom Filter (BF)`  of those partitions is created (operation 3 and 2).
The BF is passed to the `TABLEA` and is used for partition pruning on it (operation 4 and 5).

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |         |   100K|  5859K|     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI       |         |   100K|  5859K|     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   2 |   PART JOIN FILTER CREATE   | :BF0000 |     1 |    22 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL        | TABLEB  |     1 |    22 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |   PARTITION LIST JOIN-FILTER|         |   100K|  3710K|     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |:BF0000|:BF0000|
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL        | TABLEA  |   100K|  3710K|     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |:BF0000|:BF0000|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("ROW_ID"="ID")
   3 - filter("DT_COL"=SYSDATE@!)
```

See the `Pstart`, `Pstop` `:BFnnnn` as a sign of the Bloom Filter.

Answer (score 0):

Partition pruning is able to work with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and an `IN` subquery.  You are likely seeing a very specific problem that requires a more specific test case.

**Sample schema**

```
drop table tableb purge;
drop table tablea purge;

create table tablea (row_id numeric(38),tb_key numeric(38),row_data varchar(20))
 partition by list(row_id)
 (partition p1 values (1),partition p123 values(123),partition p345 values(345));
create table tableb (id numeric(38), dt_col date, tb_key numeric(38));

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TABLEA');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TABLEB');
end;
/
```

**Queries**

```
--Partition pruning works when i query from table with no joins:
explain plan for 
SELECT A.* FROM TABLEA A
WHERE ROW_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLEB WHERE DT_COL = SYSDATE);
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

--Partition Pruning fails when I do left outer join to TableB
explain plan for
SELECT A.* FROM TABLEA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TB_KEY = B.TB_KEY
WHERE ROW_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLEB WHERE DT_COL = SYSDATE);
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

--Partition Pruning works when I change left outer join to inner join
explain plan for
SELECT A.* FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TB_KEY = B.TB_KEY
WHERE ROW_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLEB WHERE DT_COL = SYSDATE);
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

--Partition Pruning works when I do left outer join to TableB and do not use IN clause
explain plan for
SELECT A.* FROM TABLEA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TB_KEY = B.TB_KEY
WHERE ROW_ID = 123;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

--Partition Pruning works when I do left outer join to TableB and use static values for IN clause
explain plan for
SELECT A.* FROM TABLEA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TB_KEY = B.TB_KEY
WHERE ROW_ID IN (123, 345);
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

**Output**

The full execution plan is not displayed here, to save space.  The only important columns are `Pstart` and `Pstop`, which imply partition pruning is used.

The execution plans look like one of the following:

```
... -----------------
... | Pstart| Pstop |
... -----------------
... 
... |   KEY |   KEY |
... |   KEY |   KEY |
... 
... -----------------

OR

... -----------------
... | Pstart| Pstop |
... -----------------
... 
... |     2 |     2 |
... |     2 |     2 |
... 
... -----------------

OR

... -----------------
... | Pstart| Pstop |
... -----------------
... 
... |KEY(I) |KEY(I) |
... |KEY(I) |KEY(I) |
... 
... -----------------
```

**How does this help?**

Not a lot.  Even though you have provided much more information than the typical question, even more information is needed to solve this problem.

At least now you know the problem is not caused by a generic limitation in partition pruning.  There is a very specific issue here, most likely related to optimizer statistics.  Getting to the bottom of such issues can require a lot of time.  I'd recommend starting from the sample data above and adding more features and data until the partition pruning goes away.

Post the new test case here, by modifying the question, and someone should be able to solve it.